# What is typescript tsserver all about?

Tags: typescript

What does `tsserver` do ?. Got a vague idea that it helps IDEs to implement features like error checking and auto-completion. But I couldn't find any API documentation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Simply speaking, it's a tool that runs TypeScript compiler in background and can quickly respond to commands like "compile this" or "autocomplete that".

It's meant to use by tool developers, and you won't need it in day-to-day work with TypeScript.

You can find source code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/src/server), it's pretty much self-explanatory.

Comment: So to install `tsserver` you install TypeScript globally e.g. `sudo yarn global add typescript`