# Are there any other TypeScript tools than tsc?

Tags: typescript

The [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html) say:

> There are two main ways to get the TypeScript tools:
>   ...

But I cannot identify any other TypeScript tools than tsc.

Are there any other TypeScript tools?

Comment: That means editor tooling like tsserver.

Comment: Immediately underneath that statement in the docs it lists the two ways to get the tools. By tools it means the typescript package. There are tons of other typescript tools, but since this is the Typescript docs, it explicitly talking about the main Typescript tool: the compiler and language server.

Comment: It is talking about ways to install `tsc`. `tsc` is the main way to transpile ts to js, although it can be done with babel as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking in node_modules/typescript/bin and you'll see two executable files:

- tsc
- tsserver

A description of tsserver has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772230/what-is-typescript-tsserver-all-about).