# Is there a TypeScript compiler API for general inferred type information from JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, compiler-construction, tsc

I was reading the [type inference documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) for TypeScript, which seem to target (quite reasonably) cases where TypeScript can surely identify types. I am curious about whether the compiler can be used to access generally inferred type information about JavaScript code. For example, is there a compiler API that would read code such as:

```js
function f(x) {
  x.q = g(x.p);
  return x.h();
}
```

and output information of the form: "`x` has a type that, at least, has a readable property called `p`, a writable property called `q`, and a callable property/method called `h`"? This is intended at a toy example, and if such an API exists, I am curious about how general it is (i.e., how precise it is for more complex cases).

Comment: given this code example the only reasonable inference is that `x.q` will be set (thought it can be set to `undefined`). There's no guarantee here that `x.p` or `x.h` are defined.

Comment: I don't know what vscode uses under the hood, but if you write that code in vscode you'll see that it will complain because `x has implicit any type`, you can click on the message and ask for suggestions, and it will advise you to assign the type `{q: any; p: any; h: Function}` to x

Comment: @CristianTraìna I think whatever VSCode is using for advice is what I am after (though I don't know how well it will generalize). Is there a way to track down what plugin is offering the advice?

Comment: I may suppose it's related to the warnings thrown by `ts-server` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772230/what-is-typescript-tsserver-all-about)), but probably the implementation of the problem resolution is something vs-code specific